# Are these two ways of installing Lubuntu with LVM both feasible and equivalent?

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, lvm, lubuntu

When installing Lubuntu using a Lubuntu bootable flash drive, there is  a step asking (see the picture below, although it is for Ubuntu not for Lubuntu)

- “Erase disk and install Lubuntu”, which has two suboptions: "Encrypt the new Lubuntu installation for security" and "Use LVM with the new Lubuntu installation";
- “Something Else”

I would like to use LVM and considering the following two ways to use LVM during the installation process:

- The first way

  1. Before installation, boot into the live Lubuntu (without installation) using a Lubuntu bootable flash drive, and create one physical volume, one volume group, and three logical volumes (for holding swap, `/` and `/home` in the next step).
  2. Reboot to start installation of Lubuntu using the Lubuntu bootable flash drive, choosing "Something Else" in the above step, and specify the logical volumes to hold swap, `/` and `/home`  respectively.

  When I tried this way,   the installation process was stuck in the next step when copying files, saying some usb errors.
- The second way:

  In the above step of installation using the Lubuntu bootable flash drive, just choose both "Erase disk and install LUbuntu" and "Use LVM with the new Lubuntu Installation".

  But the installation process doesn't ask me to create physical volume, volume group and logical volumes.

  And when it says installation completes, and  I choose to reboot, its shutdown is now stucks at  "SQUASHFS error"s: "Unable to read daa cache entry [1f5b4f7b]", "unable to read page, block 1f5b4f7b, size 4329"  and "squashfs_read_data failed to read block 0x57fa29".

Are both ways feasible?  Are they equivalent? If not what shall I do additionally to make them equivalent?

Are the problems that I encountered in the two ways unrelated to LVM and the installation?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: If possible, try installing with a different flash drive. Your current flash drive might be causing the issue here.

Comment: I can't afford another flash drive

Comment: Of cource both are  feasible. They're not the same. The first you specify your own partition scheme while the second let the installer do full-automation, which won't seperate filesystems for  / and /home. I don't know any methods to make different things equivalent. They're not unrelated to the choice you made,but related to your liveUSB.

Answer (score -3):

The second way works, it automatically creates a LV for swap with a certain size, and a LV for everything else. But after installation completes, I  need to manually adjust the size of the swap LV, and split `/` and `/home` in the other LV into two LVs, by shrinking the other LV, and creating a new LV, create a filesystem on the new LV, mount it, copy `/home` to the new LV, etc. I have met some problems, because I have never done the above before.

The first way also works. It seems simpler than the second way, and let me know if I am wrong.